# file upload tag shows null on itemtemplate gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, itemtemplate

here is my grid view in item template file upload return  null value

```
<asp:GridViewID="grdproduct"runat="server"OnRowCommand="grdproduct_RowCommand" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="change">              
                <ItemTemplate >
                   <asp:FileUpload ID="file" runat="server"></asp:FileUpload>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Please check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I don't get what you would like to achieve with that much of description

Comment: does your gridview is inside update panel?

Comment: no i dont use update panel

Comment: How are you handling the file upload in code?

Comment: ON GRID ROW COMMAND EVENT